# Evitar menú contextual al pulsar botón derecho del ratón con JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Quiero anular el ítem Pegar/Paste del menú contextual que aparece cuando se pulsa el botón derecho sobre un control `PasswordField`. He probado asignando un menú contextual vacío:

```
myPassword.setContextMenu(new ContextMenu());
```

Y aunque elimina el menú también elimina algunas opciones que si me interesan.

Pruebo a recorrer todos los ítems del contextual para anular sólo el 'Pegar/Paste' pero obtengo un error:

```
myPassword.getContextMenu().getItems().stream().forEach((item) -> {
            //eliminar opción no interesante
        });
```

El error es el siguiente:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pruebaformattext.PruebaFormatText.start(PruebaFormatText.java:71)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Exception running application pruebaformattext.PruebaFormatText
```

Answer (score 1):

En esencia la funcionalidad copiar, pegar, seleccionar, etc. que viene en el ContextMenu que trae por defecto controles como TextField, PasswordField o TextArea, hacen parte de la API no pública de JavaFX, por ello no es posible personalizarlo directamente.

Si quieres implementar nuevas funcionalidades y/o remover una o varias que vienen por defecto (como la opción de pegar) debes reescribir dichas funcionalidades. Te sugiero que revises la siguiente entrada que en esencia trata sobre el mismo problema (mira la respuesta de @James_D):

[stackoverflow.com/questions/28619605/error-when-getting-contextmenu-and-adding-new-item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619605/error-when-getting-contextmenu-and-adding-new-item)

Aquí te dejo una imagen con un PasswordTexfield que elimina la opción de 'pegar' y agrega un nuevo item 'Mi otra funcionalidad'; todo utilizando el código de @James_D y como él mismo dice la solución que plantea básicamente lo que hace es duplicar las funcionalidades que vienen por defecto y además pierde la opción de deshacer/rehacer, pero por lo demás creo que se ajusta a tus necesidades:

[image: ContextMenu personalizado]